# Last value from UNNEST collection

Tags: google-bigquery, gcloud

I'm facing a problem with the following query:

```
SELECT
   project.id as id,
   (SELECT value FROM UNNEST(project.labels) WHERE key="key1") as key1,
   (SELECT value FROM UNNEST(project.labels) WHERE key="key2") as key2,
   ROUND(SUM(cost), 2) as charges
FROM `cloud.billing.data_123`
WHERE project.id is not null and EXTRACT(MONTH FROM usage_start_time) = 6 and EXTRACT(YEAR FROM usage_start_time) = 2020
GROUP BY id, key1, key2
ORDER by id
```

It is getting the total wasted of each project, per month (in the above example, the month 6 of the 2020 year). This is report is based on Billing Report exported to [bigquery](https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/how-to/export-data-bigquery#enable-bq-export). The results are like this:

```
Row | id       | key1 | key2 | charges |
1   |project1  | null | null | 32      | 
2   |project1  | x    | y    | 40      |
3   |project2  | null | null | 50      | 
4   |project2  | x    | y    | 10      |
```

The keys are project labels and this happens because the label `key1` and `key2` were just added to the project in the middle of the month. So, the first record (with null value on keys) is the total when the project had no labels and the second record (with x and y) is the total when the project has the labels.

Is there a way to gather everything in one row with the labels and sum the values, like:

```
Row | id       | key1 | key2 | charges |
1   |project1  | x    | y    | 72      |
2   |project2  | x    | y    | 60      |
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think the query as you provided it in question has no chance to work! Nor the structure of your input data is clear! Can you please provide more details?

Comment: Hi @MikhailBerlyant, the query is working and returning the result that I added on the question description. The `cloud.billing.data_123` is the billing report that BigQuery generates automatically and `project.labels` are the labels that I added on the GCloud project. Are those the details that you said? Sorry if I wasn't made it clear.

Comment: i just don't see how it can work w/o throwing the error(s). maybe someone will help here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is my understanding that you want to sum the costs per project and output `id`,`key1`, `key2` and `cost`, having ***key1*** and ***key2*** not null.

Therefore, in order to achieve that, I will propose two ways in which I assume that for each project there are only one unique `key1` and one unique `key2`. In other words, for example, when `key1` is **null** for project1, it *should* be **x**.

**First method:** using [FIRST_VALUE()](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/navigation_functions#first_value) to fill out the the `key1` and `key2` values when they are null.

```
WITH data1 AS (
SELECT
   project.id as id,
   (SELECT value FROM UNNEST(project.labels) WHERE key="key1") as key1,
   (SELECT value FROM UNNEST(project.labels) WHERE key="key2") as key2,
   cost
FROM `cloud.billing.data_123`
WHERE project.id is not null and EXTRACT(MONTH FROM usage_start_time) = 6 and EXTRACT(YEAR FROM usage_start_time) = 2020
GROUP BY id, project, ar, activity
ORDER by id, project
),
data2 AS(
SELECT id, 
FIRST_VALUE(key1 IGNORE NULLS) OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY id ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING) AS key1,
FIRST_VALUE(key2 IGNORE NULLS) OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY id ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING) AS key2
cost
)
SELECT id, key1,key2, ROUND(SUM(cost),2) AS charges FROM data2
GROUP BY id, key1,key2
```

Notice that, ***FIRST_VALUE()*** is used with IGNORE NULLS, which finds the next available value for `key1` and `key2` within the specified partition. Thus, it is possible to sum the cost ***grouped by id, key1 and key2***.

**Second method:** Using [SELECT DISTINCT](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/query-syntax#select_distinct) and [LEFT JOIN](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/query-syntax#left_outer_join)

```
WITH data1 AS (
    SELECT
       project.id as id,
       (SELECT value FROM UNNEST(project.labels) WHERE key="key1") as key1,
       (SELECT value FROM UNNEST(project.labels) WHERE key="key2") as key2,
       cost
    FROM `cloud.billing.data_123`
    WHERE project.id is not null and EXTRACT(MONTH FROM usage_start_time) = 6 and EXTRACT(YEAR FROM usage_start_time) = 2020
    GROUP BY id, project, ar, activity
    ORDER by id, project
    ),
    data2 AS(
    SELECT DISTINCT id, key1,key2 FROM data
    WHERE key1 IS NOT NULL AND key2 IS NOT NULL
    )
    SELECT a.id,b.key1,b.key2,ROUND(SUM(cost),2) AS charges FROM data a LEFT JOIN data2 b ON a.id = b.id
    GROUP BY 1,2,3
```

The idea is the same as the first method, replacing the null values ( for `key1` and `key2`) then summing the cost for each project.

The output for both,

```
Row | id       | key1 | key2 | charges |
1   |project1  | x    | y    | 72      |
2   |project2  | x    | y    | 60      |
```

Comment: The second method worked perfectly for me. Thanks a lot, Alexandre!!!